# How to resolve "Something wicked happened resolving 'your_proxy: 800'"?

Tags: update-manager, proxy

I am not able to install any packages from terminal or software center.

> Something wicked happened resolving 'your_proxy: 800' (-5 - No address associated with hostname).

This error pops up. I need help.

Comment: - check you sources.list for errors (or add it into this question) - also check `/etc/hosts` and make sure it contains a line for 127.0.0.1 with localhost and a line 127.0.1.1 for your hostname  - allso check `/etc/hostname` and make sure that this contains your hostname - can you connect to the internet with this system? (ie. does `ping www.google.com` work? )

Comment: yes.it contains all that you have told.

Answer (score 1):

You set a proxy in your /etc/apt.conf.
Look for the line

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://your_proxy:800";
```

and either correct it with the correct proxy information or delete it.

A full line might look like:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://username:password@yourproxy:80";
```

Answer (score 0):

You set a proxy for `apt` in your system. Probably you'll find it in a file in `/etc/apt`. You can use grep to find the entry:

```
sudo grep -r your_host /etc/apt
```

If it doesn't find anything check the environment variable `http_proxy`.

However according to the error message the proxy is set to the host `your_proxy` and port `800`. But your system fails to resolve this hostname. So check the hostname for typos or other errors and try to use the correct setting. If you use the correct version, your proxy will work.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this same problem, and solved it simply by opening up my software properties

```
 software-properties-gtk
```

and changing the drop down dialog
Download from:
to Main Server.

I had trouble using the us server.

You can also switch over to your "Other Software" tab and uncheck any PPA's you have added.  Then run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and hopefully your problem will be resolved.